# bootstrap not rendering with jquery dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The below code loads a json file into my app in order to to populate some table data. It gets the job done.

```
function init_main () {
    $('html').hide().fadeIn('slow');

    // popuate from index.json
    var json = $.getJSON(chrome.extension.getURL('js/index.json'), function(json) {
        // CREATE SETTINGS TABLE WITH GIVEN INDEX
        for (var property in json) {
            var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('table');
            var header = $('<thead></thead>').addClass('thead-inverse');
            var head_r = $('<tr></tr>');
            var h1 = $('<th></th>').text(property);
            var h2 = $('<th></th>').text('check to remove: ');
            head_r.append(h1);
            head_r.append(h2);
            header.append(head_r);
            table.append(header);
            var body = $('<tbody></tbody>');
            table.append(body);
            for (var tag in json[property]) {
                var body_r = $('<tr></tr>');
                var d1 = $('<td></td>').text(tag);
                var d2 = $('<td></td>')     // maybe change to class?
                $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: tag}).appendTo(d2);
                body_r.append(d1);
                body_r.append(d2);
                body.append(body_r);
            }
            $('#tableWrap').append(table);
        }
    });
}

//bind events to dom elements
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init_main);
```

*However, unlike the rest of my html markup, **only these elements will not use the bootstrap library** to alter my CSS*. All other html markup successfully uses the bootstrap library.

I have tried moving the code outside of the callback with no luck. No errors in console.

**Does anyone have any idea why bootstrap wont come into effect during the above code snippet?** I think it has something to do with page load but so far I have not seen any success with window.onPageLoad()

Here are my script imports in my html for reference:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- load stylesheets: Bootstrap v2.3.0 - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>

        <!-- load javascript: jQuery 1.9.1 - http://jquery.com/ -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

        <!-- load javascript: Bootstrap v2.3.0 - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- load stylesheets: internal -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/global.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a id="home" id="active" class="brand" href="#">
            <!-- UNCOMMENT THE CSS VALUES TO TEST OTHER DIMENTIONS -->
            <img src="../images/icon.png" alt=""> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            Fluff 1.0
            </a>
            <a id="settings" class ="brand" href="#" >
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            Settings</a>
            <a id="run" class ="brand" href="#" >
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            Run</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="outer">
            <!-- Main Page -->
            <div id="main-inner">
                <div id="main-title"> Fluff 1.0 </div>
                <div id="textblock">Donate or contact block here</div>
            </div>
            <!-- Settings Page -->
            <div id="settings-inner">
                <h5 id="directions"> <span></span> Select Tags to Remove from Automated Browser Queries </h5>
                <div id="tableWrap">

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Run Page -->
            <div id="run-inner">
                <table class='table'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 1 </td>
                            <td> 2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- load javascript: unique html page javascript file -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

**edit:** sample.json - *'num' key is not relevant in any of the question or code*

```
{
    "sex": {
        "M":{   
                "num":13,
            },
        "F": {
                "num":13,
            },
        "T": {
                "num":0
        }
    },
    "politics": {
        "L": {  
                "num":10,
            },
        "R": {
                "num":10,
        }
    },
    "race": {
        "AMI":{
                "num":6,
        },
        "ASI":{
                "num":7,
        },
        "AFA":{
                "num":7,
        },
        "PCI":{
                "num":0
        },
        "WHT":{
                "num":2,
                "3":"-"
        },
        "HSP":{
                "num":5,
                "6":"-"
        },
        "MDE":{
                "num":6,
        }
    },
    "orientation": {
        "STR": {
                "num":0
        },
        "GAY": {
                "num":0
        },
        "OTH": {
                "num":0
        }
    },
    "interests": {
        "GARD":{
                "num":4,
        },
        "NHL":{
                "num":1,
        },
        "NBA":{
                "num":1,
        },
        "TECH":{
                "num":0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not create the table in cshtml and append only the rows using javascript?

Comment: dynamic number of tables too.

Comment: Could you put your sample json here?

Comment: @SiamakFerdos sure thing. updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing `div id='tableWrap'` to `table id='tableWrap'` in html

Tables inside of tables ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem exactly, but I put your sample in jsfiddle by removing some unuseful html file to make it simple to read and this works. Only code which is wrong is `var json = $.getJSON`. Why you do it? however you have not any returned value at all and if it was it never works in async functions like `get`. 
The second problem is that you never call your function!!

See this code and share your idea with me:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/982exLzn/)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The code already correctly created the tables as your jsfiddle shows. The problem is that the tables created in the code snippet do not render with the bootstrap library. Bootstrap, however, is working with other parts of the project because all other html markup is being rendered correctly.

Comment: My data being used to create the tables is coming from a json file. So I am using $.getJSON to load my json data file into a var.

Comment: So as I understand, you want create table by bootstrap API not as your code sample in this post. Am I right?